# Get whether a blocking lock blocked

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, thread-safety, race-condition

In Python 3, I want to acquire a lock and then know whether it blocked or not. The problem is that `threading.Lock.acquire` always returns `True` if it is called with `blocking=True`, so there is no way to tell whether the lock was already locked at the moment when the function was called. Take this code for example:

```
import threading

foo = None
lock = threading.Lock()

def bar():
    global foo
    # Only compute foo in one thread at a time.
    if not lock.acquire(blocking=False):
        # The race condition exists here.
        # Another thread is already computing foo.
        # This instance does not need to recompute foo.
        # Wait for that instance to finish.
        with lock:
            # Just return the value that the other instance computed.
            return foo
    # No other instance of this function is computing foo.
    with lock:
        # Compute foo.
        foo = [something]
        return foo
```

The problem here is that `lock` can be acquired again where a comment in the code above says that a race condition exists.

If this is because a third thread is at the same point in the function continued first and acquired the lock, this is undesirable because it introduces a slight delay. There really is no reason that `return foo` needs to be protected; two threads should be able to do it at the same time.

However, if the acquire is due to another thread recomputing `foo`, then this is undesirable because `foo` will have changed once the lock is released. The function should return the value of `foo` that was being computed when it was called. If `foo` changes, then it cannot return that value anymore.

Ideally, we would have an `acquire` function that can block and still return whether it blocked or not. That way, we can confidently assert that the function always returns the value of `foo` that was being computed when the function was called and that only if `foo` was not already being computed does the function then go ahead, compute it, and return the new value. Can this be done in Python?

Comment: Have you tried `lock.locked()`?

Comment: @Sraw Hm, no, what is that? I don't see it on https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#threading.Lock.

Comment: Well, `Return the status of the lock: True if it has been acquired by some thread, False if not.`

Comment: @Sraw How is that different than `not lock.acquire(False)`? It does not block if the lock is locked.

Comment: Um... No, no difference in your case. I just give that comment based on your title. Admittedly I don't fully understand your description. If a thread releases the lock after compution, `foo` will still be re-computed in next call. How do you determine if it is need to be computed? Maybe a normal `if foo: \n return foo` is enough?

Comment: If `bar` is called while `bar` is already running in another thread, this `bar` should wait for the other `bar` to finish and return `foo` from that `bar`. If `bar` is called while `bar` is not already running in another thread, it should go ahead and recompute `foo`.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Whether or not the lock was already held when you call `lock.acquire()` is irrelevant. Which is why  lock acquisition functions typically don't return an indicator as to whether or not they had to wait for the lock to be released. Just acquire the lock and check if `foo` has been initialized. If it has, return it, else compute and return it.

Comment: @KurtisRader The problem is that `foo` may be recomputed before `bar` can unblock and return it, and `bar` needs to return the value of `foo` that was being computed when it was called. What I may do, however, is store the last few values of `foo` in a dictionary. Whenever `foo` is computed, it gets a unique ID. If `foo` is being computed when `bar` is called in another thread, it simply gets the ID of the value that is currently being computed and just retrieves that value using the ID whenever it gets unblocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question is old, but since I stumbled on it while looking for something else and it is unanswered, I figured I'd do anyone who finds it a service and answer it.

You are causing the race condition by first checking if a lock is available. You should try acquiring the lock without checking, like so:

```
import threading

foo = None
lock = threading.Lock()

def bar():
    global foo
    # Only compute foo in one thread at a time.
    with lock:
        # Only compute foo once.
        if foo is None:
            foo = [something]
        # Just return the value that is now guaranteed to be computed.
        return foo
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, simply checking whether `foo` is computed before computing it works. I guess that I was having a brain fart three years ago.